# Configuration deluge on tor

Tags: tor, torrent

I know we already talked about this, but the Q&A I found here and googling doesn't suit my issue.

I've read that I shouldn't do that for several reasons (and take a look to the alternatives and probably an affordable seedbox will be the best option). Even though that, I'm struggling to get it working but currently I cant.

Based on what I read, to get it work, first all I have to run Tor browser and successful initiate it. I got that, tor browser running with all ok.
Then I launched Deluge, Edit -> Preferences, and for each field (Peer, Web seeds, Tracker and DHT) Sockv5, 127.0.0.1, port 9050 and restart Deluge.
But doesn't work at all... Deluge is working good without that configuration.

I've been trying to track that with Wireshark, I noticed that source port for TCP Tor connections is 9666. Also tried that port and get nothing. Also tried as Sockv4 and Sockv5 W/ Auth. Ping at 127.0.0.1 is ok and I can 'ssh 127.0.0.1'.

nmap 127.0.0.1 -> 22/25/80/111/631/9418 are open.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Recommend that you disable certain features to stay anonymous when using a SOCKS proxy, click the network tab on the side menu, under "Network Extra's" disable UPNP/NAT-PMP, to disable them you just need to click them once, then click apply and then OK.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I wouldn't use Tor for torrents, as it's horribly slow, plus torrent clients are prone to leaking info even when properly configured to use Tor. You're better off getting Private Internet Access or TorGuard for three or four bucks a month.

I guess if you really wanted to do this, [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/) would be an option, as 100% of traffic would be funneled through Tor. But again, I would go for the VPN option.